# Cannot group JSON array because of typecasting error

Tags: json, swift

I have an API that returns an array of dictionaries and I'm trying to group it by the `date` key in each item using Swift's `Dictionay(grouping:)` function.
The JSON looks like this:

```
[
    { "date": "2018-12-12", "name": "abc" },
    { "date": "2018-12-12", "name": "def" },
    { "date": "2018-12-13", "name": "def" },
    ...
]
```

I have the following swift code that generates a compilation error:

```
let json = response.result.value as! Array<[String:AnyObject]>
let groupedByDate = Dictionary(grouping: json, by: { (item) -> String in
    return (item as! [String:AnyObject])["date"]
})
```

When I compile I get this error:

```
Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'String'
```

and this warning:

```
Cast from '_' to unrelated type '[String : AnyObject]' always fails
```

I'm very confused because the `item` variable is clearly of type `[String:AnyObject]` and I am able to index into the json in the debugger by doing `po json[0]["date"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contradicts itself. When you say

```
let groupedByDate = Dictionary(grouping: json, by: {
    (item) -> String in
```

you are making a contract that you will return a String from this closure.

But when you then say

```
return (item as! [String:AnyObject])["date"]
```

you are returning an AnyObject, not a String.

Comment: Thanks! The error was somewhat misleading, or maybe i Just misinterpreted it. I casted the entire expression to a string and it works. And I was able to condense everything to this: `let groupedByDate = Dictionary(grouping: json, by: { $0["date"] as! String })`

Comment: You're not going to get me to defend a Swift compiler error message! I suppose I could figure out what the compiler must be thinking, but it's not worth the worry.